# Corrupted output when using pdf2svg with cmbright

Tags: fonts, pdftex, tools

Please consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\begin{document}
    Math: $A/2=\cos(\phi(t))$
\end{document}
```

The output created with `pdflatex` looks flawless:
[image]

But the result of a conversion with `pdf2svg` is terrible (viewed in Inkscape):
[image]

This is the ouput of `pdffonts` for the resulting pdf file:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no       4  0
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no       5  0
```

There is no problem without `cmbright` (SVG output in Inkscape):
[image]

And here is the corresponding output of `pdffonts`:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
HWJCRU+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       4  0
QOYABT+CMMI10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       5  0
```

What does cause the pixelated output and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the Type1 fonts of `cmbright` which are called "hfbright" and can be downloaded from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ps-type1/hfbright). With these fonts installed the result of the SVG conversion looks correct (viewed in Inkscape):

[image]

I'll describe how to install the Type1 fonts for TexLive on an Ubuntu system, because installation did not work for me as described in the README file coming with the fonts. (The installation instructions there are for teTex)

## Step 1

[Download](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/ps-type1/hfbright.zip) the package and unpack it to some directory, say `hfbright-dir`

## Step 2

The install script `hfbright-dir/install.sh` coming with the package has to be modified. Replace lines 17-19 with the following lines:

```
FONTS="$TEXMFMAIN/fonts/type1/public/hfbright"
METRICS="$TEXMFMAIN/fonts/afm/public/hfbright"
DVIPSDIR="$TEXMFMAIN/dvips/config"
```

I have replaced occurences of `TEXMFLOCAL` with `TEXMFMAIN` here.

## Step 3

Change to `hfbright-dir` and execute the install script as root:

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

Make the new files known to your TexLive installation:

```
sudo mktexlsr
```

Finally, rebuild the font map:

```
sudo updmap-sys
```